# Category property in Google App Engine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Category property in Google App Engine - Java?

the Constructor of Category just takes String. I am not sure whether we can use Category for the Multi value property. Any input or example on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find an usage of Category property. So, I am trying to use List

```
Setting the property as mentioned below:
//tags can contain TAG1, TAG2, TAG3, etc
List<String> tags;
entity.setProperty("tags", tags);
```

Querying the property as mentioned below:

```
String tag = "TAG1";
Query q = new Query("EntityType").setAncestor(parentEntity.getKey()).setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("tags", tag));
```

Getting the property as mentioned below:

```
List<String> tags = (List<String>)entity.getProperty("tags");
```